# Eclipse import from required project not working

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i have a project in my workspace that i build with maven following these instructions: http://sweble.org/repos/ 
Now i want to make another project that uses some classes from that project. I added the sweble project as a required project to my new project. `(Properties->Java Build Path->Projects->Add`).

The classes from the sweble project are now suggested via autocomplete and if i use them it automatically adds imports to my class, but after saving that class those imports are marked with the error "The import org.sweble cannot be resolved".

I cannot resolve this error. I find it very strange that autocomplete works but the actual import doesn't.

The src folder of the sweble project is called `src/main/java` and it contains the package `"org.sweble.wikitext.dumpreader"` the import that gets suggested is called: `"import org.sweble.wikitext.dumpreader.DumpReader;"`

Does anybody know how to resolve this error or what might be misconfigured here?

Comment: If you are sure that the library Sweble is added to your project build path, maybe you can try to "clean" the project. In eclipse under Project - Clean

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have to pull the git repo? maybe you can just add Sweble like any other mavenized project to your project's pom.xml? see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sweble/sweble/1.1.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sweble</groupId>
    <artifactId>sweble</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```